# Bison %prec doesn't work

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I'm implementing a simple calculator with flex and bison.

I'd like the following input to give -4 and not 4:

```
-2^2
```

In order to achieve -4, I had to declare the priority of ^ operator to be higher than the priority of the unary minus operator, but it doesn't work.

This is the bison code:

```
%{

#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
void yyerror(const char *s);
int yylex();

%}


%union  {   
    int    int_val;
    char*  string_val;
    double double_val;

}


%token INTEGER 
%left '+' '-'
%left '*' '/' '%'
%left UMINUS UPLUS
%right '^'

%type <int_val> expr_int INTEGER

%%

program: line '\n'
        | '\n'          { return 0; }
        ;

line: expr_int {    cout<<$1<<endl; return 0;   }
        ;


expr_int: expr_int '+' expr_int          { $$ = $1 + $3; }
        | expr_int '-' expr_int           { $$ = $1 - $3; }
        | expr_int '*' expr_int           { $$ = $1 * $3; }
        | expr_int '^' expr_int           { $$ = pow($1,$3); }
        | '-' INTEGER %prec UMINUS          { $$ = -$2; }
        | '+' INTEGER %prec UPLUS           { $$ = $2; }
        | INTEGER           
        ;

%%

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    printf("error");
}


int main(void) {
    while(yyparse()==0);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the flex code:

```
%{

#include <iostream>
#include "calc.tab.h"

using namespace std;

void yyerror(const char *s);


%}


INTEGER     [1-9][0-9]*|0
UNARY       [+|\-]
BINARY      [+|\-|*|^|]
WS          [ \t]+


%%

{INTEGER}               {   yylval.int_val=atoi(yytext); return INTEGER;    }

{UNARY}|{BINARY}|\n     {   return *yytext; }

{WS}                    {}
.                       {}

%%

//////////////////////////////////////////////////
int yywrap(void) { return 1;  }  // Callback at end of file
```

Why doesnt bison first handle 2^2 and then adds the unary minus, like I defined?
It keep printing 4 instead...

Thanks alot for the helpers.

Comment: Nice to see you know that exponentiation is right-associative. You don't really need the UNARY rule in the lexer.

Comment: `[+|\-]` matches any of the three characters `+`, `|` or `-`. I don't think you wanted to accept `|`. Also, you don't need to escape the `-` if it is either first or last in the character class. So you could just write `[+-]` or `[-+]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your syntax for unary minus:

```
 '-' INTEGER %prec UMINUS
```

does not allow its argument to be an expression. So it unambiguously grabs the following `INTEGER` and the `%prec` rule is never needed.

---

<personal_opinion>
The problem with `%prec` is that yacc/bison does not complain if the rule is not needed. So you never really know if it does anything or not. IMHO it's really better to just write an unambiguous grammar.

Comment: +1 Well spotted, I should have seen that. I agree with your comment. I much prefer to write out the standard expression grammar with terms and factors and all that.

Comment: @rici: well, actually Bison does complain about useless `%prec`.  Unless you mean something else?  See "precedence" here: http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Bison-Options

Comment: @akim: That's cool. But: you need to use bison3, which is not yet very common in distros, *and* you need to specifically ask bison to produce the warning (or use `-Wall`), which is undoubtedly a good idea but is not common knowledge. (I'll start recommending it, though.) And even then, it doesn't complain about the "%prec"; it complains about the declaration of `UMINUS` and `UPLUS`. It's certainly a step forward. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. But I think "Bison *does* complain" is a bit overstated. "New versions of Bison can complain if you ask them nicely..." :)